# Assume that A is a subset of some underlying universal set U.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

7. Prove the domination laws in Table 1 by showing that
   a) A ∪ U = U.

here is the answer but i have no idea how to come up with this answer and where does T come from?:O
A ∪ U = {x | x ∈ A ∨ x ∈ U}={x | x ∈ A ∨ T} =
{x | T} = U

Thanks

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but, does your book use any particular symbols for the truth values, "true" and "false"? If so, do you have a way of finding out what they are? Like, does your book have an alphabetical index at the back, or a list of symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this kind of problem is to exploit the correspondence between *algebra of sets* and *propositional logic*.

Specifically, the defining condition for the *union* between sets is :

> $(x \in A \cup B)$ **iff** $(x \in A$ **or** $x \in B)$.

Consider now $A \cup U$, where $U$ is the *universal* set, i.e. such that : for all $x$, $x \in U$. Applying the above definition, we have that :

> $(x \in A \cup U)$ **iff** $(x \in A$ **or** $x \in U)$.

But $x \in U$ is always *true*; applying propositional logic :

> $(x \in A \cup U)$ **iff** $(x \in A$ **or** TRUE) **iff** TRUE

because by [Domination laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) of propositional logic : $p \lor TRUE \equiv TRUE$.

But TRUE in the algebra of sets can be expressed as $x \in U$, that is always *true*; thus :

> $(x \in A \cup U)$ **iff** $(x \in U)$

and this is :

> > $A \cup U = U$.