# Prove the Domination Laws Using The Elementwise Approach

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Solve *A* ∪ *U* = *U*

I understand how it is solved in this link, as we recently went over propositional logic: [Assume that A is a subset of some underlying universal set U.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990031/assume-that-a-is-a-subset-of-some-underlying-universal-set-u)

From my understanding, elementwise is showing that if x is an element in A and x is an element in B, then A is a subset of B.

By that understanding, I thought that to solve the problem mentioned above, it should be done as follows:

> $(x \in A) \,   or \, (x \in U)$

After this point I am a bit unsure on how to proceed. I understand that *A* is a subset of *U*.

Edit:

> $( A ⊆ U)$ iff for all  $x \in A, x \in U.$

I read in my textbook that to show that if $( A ⊆ U)$ and $( U ⊆ A)$, then A = U, which can then be used to show that $( U \cup U)$ = *U*

The proof for this should then be to first show $( A ⊆ U)$, which we did above.

Then show that $( U ⊆ A)$. Is this something that can be done?

Edit: I believe that in this case, it should be shown as $( A \cup U ⊆ U)$ and as $( U ⊆ A \cup U)$ as the book said that $( A ⊆ B)$ and $( B ⊆ A)$ means that A = B.

> $( A \cup U ⊆ U)$ can be done by showing that if $(x \in A) or (x \in U), then x \in U $ based on the definition of a subset.

$( U ⊆ A \cup U )$ can be shown by saying that if $x \in U, then x \in U or x \in A, therefore $( U ⊆ A \cup U )$ .

Because we showed that $( U ⊆ A \cup U )$  and $( A \cup U ⊆ U)$ , $A = U$ and $U \cup U = U$

Comment: "From my understanding, element-wise is showing that if x is an element in A and x is an element in B, then A is a subset of B."  No, that's not right.  A simple example will prove your definition of a subset is wrong/incomplete:  Let $A = \{1, 2\}, \; B=\{2, 3\}.$. Suppose $x = 2$.  Then $x \in A$ and $x\in B$. But $A\not\subseteq B$.  We need to use the correct definition of a subset A of B: that $A\subseteq B \iff \forall x(x\in A \rightarrow x\in B).$

Answer (score 1):

Notice the definition for set containing is that:

> $A \subseteq U$, iff $\forall x \in A$, we have $x \in U$

Now bear this in our mind, let's do the proof:
If $A \subseteq U$, then $\forall x \in A,\, x \in U$

Then if $x \in A\cup U$, we have $x \in A$ (And thus $x \in U$) or $x\in U$. Thus, both situation leads to $x\in U$. So we have $A \cup U \subseteq U$

If $x \in U$, we know $x \in A \cup U$, thus $U \subseteq A \cup U$

Thus $A\cup U = U$

Comment: For where you said that A is a proper subset of Universe if and only if for every x in A, that x is an element in Universe, correct? I thought that a proper subset meant that there was an x in Universe that wasn't there in x. From the proof that you gave, I understand that A is proper subset of U, therefore for all x in A, there is an x in Universe? Therefore if x is an element in A or U, for x being an element in A, it is also in U along with x being an element in U due to the definition of union. Therefore x is an element in U or x is an element in U, therefore U is a subset of A u U is U

Comment: No. I agree the notation $\subset$ could be understood by proper subset, or subset. My habit is to denote for subset, but I know some people like to think it as proper subset, instead of just subset. Different math books tend to have different notation over this too. But the definition itself clarified which notation this is referring to - should be refer to subset, not proper subset.

Comment: I edit the answer to use $\subseteq$ instead for clarification. So I read through your logic in the comment, your understanding is correct. Just want to clarify that we are not talking about proper subset, but just subset in general.

Comment: I made an edit. I reread the section in my book and it led me to make the edit from above

Comment: please let me know if my edited work makes sense. I feel like I have grasp on it

Comment: Not quite make sense to me. Why do you want to show $U \subseteq A$? What are you trying to show?

Comment: I made a mistake. I misunderstood the logic that the book was trying to show. I edited it right after toc orrect myself.